# How to tell PyCharm that async fixture returns something

Tags: python, async-await, pycharm, pytest

Example:

```
import pytest


@pytest.fixture
async def phrase():
    return 'hello world'


@pytest.fixture
async def replaced(phrase):
    return phrase.replace('hello', 'goodbye')
```

The method `.replace` is yellow-colored and the warning says:

```
Unresolved attribute reference 'replace' for class 'Coroutine'
```

However, these fixtures are working. If I remove `async` from `def phrase():` Pycharm is handling `.replace` correctly, showing that it is method of class `str`. Is there any way to tell PyCharm that `phrase` when used in `replaced` will be an instance of `str`, not a `Coroutine`? Preferably, without code repetition for every fixture that will use `phrase`.

Comment: Just a wild guess: does type hinting with `: str` work?

Comment: Unfortunatelly, no.

Comment: `yield 'hello world'` instead of `return`ing.

Comment: @hoefling it works! Consider writing an answer? Maybe you know why `yield` works but `return` doesn't?

Comment: seems https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/14202-pytest-imp/ fixes this issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not your code, it's a Pycharm issue - it doesn't resolve return types of native coroutine fixtures correctly. Pycharm will resolve the old generator-based coroutine fixture

```
@pytest.fixture
async def phrase():
    yield 'hello world'
```

as a [`Generator[str, Any, None]`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Generator) and map the argument to the fixture's return type. However, a native coroutine fixture

```
@pytest.fixture
async def phrase():
    return 'hello world'
```

is a [`Coroutine[Any, Any, str]`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Coroutine) and currently, Pycharm doesn't map the test args to its return type (tested with Pycharm CE 2019.1). You thus have two possibilities:

#### Set explicit type hints

Since you know what the coroutines should return, set the return and arg types and Pycharm will stop guessing. This is the most straightforward and robust approach:

```
@pytest.fixture
async def phrase() -> str:
    return 'hello world'


@pytest.fixture
async def replaced(phrase: str) -> str:
    return phrase.replace('hello', 'goodbye')
```

#### Switch to generator-based coroutine fixtures

This would mean `yield`ing instead of `return`ing as I suggested in the comments; however, it's up to you whether you should change the obviously correct code just to work around Pycharm's issue.

Comment: Explicit type hints (both `-> str` and `: str`) doesn't help PyCharm to understand that `phrase` is a `str`. :(

Comment: What Pycharm version are you using? Setting explicit type hints works with Pycharm CE 2019.1, not sure about older versions though.

Comment: Professional 2018.3

Comment: I will test the issue with 2018.3 Pro tomorrow on a colleague's machine; however, the essential type hint should be the test arg (`replaced(phrase: str)`). The fixture return types are indeed negligible; I inserted them for completeness sake.

Comment: don't believe this is still open issue

Comment: https://github.com/theY4Kman/pycharm-pytest-imp this plugin fixes that issue